# Somewhat new to html and css

Tags: html, css

I´ve been working with Html for a bit these last 2 weeks and just started css today. I understand some of the basics of css (some of the elements and how to make the code look neater) but there are a few things i dont quite understand and haven´t been able to find so far. Such as making an image smaller for example. Can anyone explain to me why this css code isn't working?

```css
h1{
  Color: #8a1319
}
.name {
  color: #ba454b;
}
/*help with this part please? Cant figure out how to properly make it smaller*/
.joke{
  border: 2px solid red;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 50%;
}
body {
  text-align:center;
  background: powderblue
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  <h1>Dylan Carlson</h1>
</div>
<section>
  <h1 class="title">
    website
  </h1>
  <p>
    <div class=joke>
    <img src=http://www.jeremychin.com/repository/tickled/0355.jpg class=image />
    <div>
      <br>
      <br> Age: 17
      <br>
      <br> Grade:12
      <br>
      <br> Intrest: programming
      <br>
      <br> extra curricular: N/A
      <br>
      <img src=https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTSJjXu1Ulhi3ExUJYOsgRxEcXywik5FG2B-ouj4E3RqgDIARssdQ>
    </div>
  </p>
  <p>
    Favorite Icecream: IDFK
    <br>
    <br> 
    Favorite color: Gold/Black
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow.  We value **high quality** questions that have a high probability of helping others in the future.  Questions like yours, which many consider to be "debug this code", are not recommended. I'd suggest you try searching on the internet for references (try mdn) on HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the DIV around the image and add joke to the class:

```
<img src="http://www.jeremychin.com/repository/tickled/0355.jpg" class="joke">
```

Since you had `joke` as a class of the DIV, it applied to the DIV and NOT the IMG.  Thus, the max height of the DIV was 250px and since the picture was larger, it overlapped.

A bit of advice: Keep CSS at the lowest level you can (the IMG in this case and not the DIV).

Comment: Oh my.... thank you XD It works now. I completely forgot i had set the div around it in the first place

Comment: Also I HIGHLY HIGHLY recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript).  It will make your life so much eaiser.

Answer (score 0):

You are editing the image's parent div, that's why it's not working. Use the image's class instead.

```
.image{
  border: 2px solid red;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Css is not for creating things on the browser it is for styling elements. Ii is used to make things look as desired. The code as per your question will make a div (if styled on to) have a border with 2px in size with red colour and the div would be having width 50 percent as per the availability space and a maximum height of 250px